# Step into framework

Tags: xcode, cocoa

For example I want to look at `[VZVirtualMachine isSupported]` implementation. I created a console project, run it with debug, stepped into this method but all it does is wander around objc_msgSend implementation, at least my patience was not enough to wait until it finds the actual implementation. Is there some way to set a breakpoint closer to the actual code?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `+[VZVirtualMachine isSupported]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VZVirtualMachine is an Apple proprietary class. Its implementation source code is not shipped. What you have is optimized assembly language. If you want something that can generate pseudo-ObjC or pseudo-C from it, there are tools like [Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com/) and [IDA Pro](https://hex-rays.com/ida-pro/) that can help, but they're not going to give you anything like the original source code if that's what you're looking for. To get that, you'd need access to Apple's source.

Comment: I understand that I will read assembly code, that's fine. I just want to understand how to jump to the actual code, because objc_msgSend is definitely not it.

Comment: The debugger doesn't know the difference between "important" and "unimportant" functions. objc_msgSend is quite magical (it's a trampoline and doesn't have a proper stack frame), so generally you'll just need to step through it. You can try the "return from stack-frame" button (looks like an up-arrow with a line at the top) if you get down into proper functions that you want to pop out of. But stepping through ObjC assembly, you're going to go through objc_msgSend a lot, yes.

Comment: I hoped to find some lldb command like "continue until next function call" but I guess there's no such command.